# how to dynamically select the range of cells in excel using macros

Tags: excel, vba

Am comparing two excel workbooks using Macros. While navigating from one excel to Second excel I want to dynamically select the range of cells in second excel rather than mentioning the cell number using range command. In turn, I want to use this selection of cells in the vlookup command in first excel.
this is how my piece of code looks when i recorded the macros:

```
Range("O2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _"=VLOOKUP(RC[-14],[book.xls]sheet1.!R2C1:R284C14,12,FALSE)"
Columns("O:O").Select
```

How can I dynamically select the data present in the second Excel instead of using specific cell number?

Comment: which value you want to put inside the `VLookup` formula as range ? is it `Range("O2")` , or `Columns("O:O")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question and code are not very clear. Please remember to add four spaces before every line of code.

It sounds like you want to use something like:

```
for i = 1 to 100
    activesheet.cell(i,15).FormulaR1C1 = _          
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-14],book.xls]sheet1.!R2C1:R284C14,12,FALSE)
next
```